# как удалить значение из объекта?

Tags: javascript

я получаю значение из инпута, если оно есть в объекте, оно должно удаляться

мой код выглядит так:

```js
let a12 = {"b": 17,"e": 22,"j": 17,"k": 26,"d": 1};

function f12() {

    let input = document.querySelector(".i-12")

    console.log(
      Object.values(a12).includes(input.value)
      ? delete a12[input.value]
      : ""
    )
    console.log(a12)
}


document.querySelector('.b-12').onclick = f12;
```

```html
<input class="i-12" placeholder="key"/>
<button class="b-12">del</button>
```

Comment: `Object.keys()` надо а не `values` проверять, закрыть опечаткой

Comment: @teran, с чего ты взял, что ему не values надо? И вообще, нафига проверять keys?

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что далее по коду он input.value как ключ в delete передает, очевидно? проверять не зачем, но если проверять, то не значения а ключи

Comment: @teran, при том, что это ещё и в console.log запихнуто, я бы этому куску кода не доверял. А вопрос сформулирован _"значение из объекта",_ а не "ключ" и даже не "свойство".

Comment: @Qwertiy хз зачем запихано, но при успехе delete вернет true, так что какой-то смысл есть

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = { b:17, e:22, j:17, k:26, d:1, undefined:42 }

function del(val) {
  for (var [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (v == val) {
      delete obj[k]
    }
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))

del("26")
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))

del("zzz")
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))

del(42)
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Если вопрос сводится к тому, как из словаря `A` удалить значение по ключу `x`.

Объекты в JavaScript можно рассматривать как ассоциативные массивы (словари).

Чтобы удалить значение из объекта в JavaScript, можно применить оператор удаления `delete`, где результат вычисления выражения должен быть ссылкой на свойство (объекта), например:

```
delete object.property
delete object['property']
delete object[index]
delete property // удаляет свойства глобального объекта
```

Этот оператор может быть применён к свойству, которое и так отсутствовало в объекте: в таком случае, никакой модификации объекта не произойдёт. Выражение вернёт `false`. В случае успешного удаления будет возвращаться `true`.

Таким образом получаем решение:

```js
let a12 = {"b": 17,"e": 22,"j": 17,"k": 26,"d": 1};

function f12() {
    let input = document.querySelector(".i-12");

    delete a12[input.value];
    console.log(a12);
}


document.querySelector('.b-12').onclick = f12;
```

```html
<input class="i-12" placeholder="key"/>
<button class="b-12">del</button>
```

#### Если вопрос сводится к тому, как из словаря `A` удалить значение со значением `y`.

Нужно определить ключи, значения при которых совпадают со введённым значением. Можно воспользоваться циклом с проверкой. Но, опять же, будут удалены все такие значения. Чтобы удалилось лишь первое - нужно раскомментировать строку

```js
let a12 = {"b": 17,"e": 22,"j": 17,"k": 26,"d": 1};

function f12() {
    let input = document.querySelector(".i-12");

    for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(a12)) {
        if (value == input.value) {
            delete a12[key];
            //раскомментировать, если нужно удалить лишь первый
            //break;
        }
    }
    console.log(a12);
}


document.querySelector('.b-12').onclick = f12;
```

```html
<input class="i-12" placeholder="value"/>
<button class="b-12">del</button>
```

Comment: В вопросе сказано, что надо удалить не по ключу, а по значению. И кусок кода `Object.values(a12).includes(input.value)` это подтверждает. Так что, наверное, надо бы ответ немного подправить. Хотя смущает плейсхолдер `key`...

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо, дополнил ответ этим кейсом

Answer (score 0):

Попалась такая же, как у автора, задачка на курсах.
Я так сделал - работает:

```
let a12 = {
    "b": 17,
    "e": 22,
    "j": 17,
    "k": 22,
    "d": 17,
};

function f12() {
    let inp12 = +document.querySelector('.i-12').value;
    let out = '';

    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(a12)) {
        if (value === inp12) {
            delete a12[key];
        }
         else {
             out += `${key} : ${a12[key]},<br> `
         }
    }
     document.querySelector('.out-12').innerHTML = out;
    
}

document.querySelector('.b-12').onclick = f12;
```